# How to 'partially' install a Python package

Tags: python, numpy, pip, python-wheel

I need to use a function in `numpy` package, say `numpy.random.choice` (another Python lib function `random.choice` samples the list uniformly while I want it to do that from some discrete distributions).

My program will be distributed to a lot of people to develop and test. So that means they should also install `numpy` before they are able to run the code. I'm now trying to find a way to get rid of installing the whole numpy library.

Definitely rewriting the function myself is a solution (for example using alias method). But I'm wondering that is there a way that I can only install the part of `numpy` related to `numpy.random.choice`?

Comment: Why would you want to do that?

Comment: With numpy specifically, I highly doubt this would be possible. Numpy is written in C and compiled on each machine during installation. To install some small component should therefore be pretty hard. I really think it would be easier to write your own version of `numpy.random.choice` (or extract just that code out of the C source) as a new package

Comment: Is `random.choice` not an acceptable substitute?

Comment: @IanAuld As I pointed out in my post, it is not, as it can only generate from uniform distribution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is probably not worth the hassle but it's up to you to make that trade-off. `numpy.random.choice` is not implemented in Python but in a `.pyx` file which needs to be compiled to C using Cython.

You could refactor it and construct a new package which implements only that functionality (possibly with a few related data structures). But with recent improvements with Python wheels files installation of `numpy` should be much easier than in the past. So I reckon it's easier to install `numpy` as it is and accept that you have it as a dependency.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. After searching on internet and asking here, It seems that for simple functions like 'numpy.random.choice', rewriting is a better solution.